# How can we transfer session id using Curl?

Tags: php, curl, session-state

We have a server and multiple clients. If user logged in at server, session is created on user_id at server and we redirect client to server using OpenId.

But before we redirect to client, I want to get this session user id using curl and redirect only if the session exist on client.

Can we do this using PHP sessions without cookies ?

Comment: Well, there are only two ways to transmit the session ID: URL and cookies. Whatever, I can't understand your architecture. Do you want to transmit the PHP session ID to the OpenID server? Why can't you use cookies, company policy?

Comment: Thanks for reply. No, Its like we want the browser to automatically redirect to open id server only if the user session exist at server. We can use cookies too, but how can we do this with cross domain. Server is on different domain and client on its own domain. We wanted to see if we can use Curl to check if cookie exist on server.

Comment: Sorry but I still find it hard to follow you. You have two servers and you call both of them "Server" :-? Do you want to *share* a session identifier between two different servers?

Comment: We have a OpenID server and to Client Servers A & B. a user can login to both A & B with same OpenId, now, if user is already logged in client A, and now types url of Client B in browser, he should be automatically logged in. We are struggling with how to do this :)

Comment: Anyway, PHP session relies on cookies. Try reading [this man page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.idpassing.php) about passing session ID. But I don't get where your want to use curl.Sounds off topic.

Answer (score 0):

As sessions are cookie anyway, the easiest way is to alter your cookie with `domain:sitea,siteb`. 
The other way is to pass it in the url, but it won't work if the user manually types `http://siteb.whatever/` in his browser.

For instance:

```
header("Set-Cookie: $mySessionId; Domain=siteA.com; Path=/exemple/of/path; Secure;");
header("Set-Cookie: $mySessionId; Domain=siteB.com; Path=/; Secure;");
```

Will create two cookies, wich will be resend each time you connect to `siteA.com/exemple/of/path/` or to `siteB.com/`. They'll be deleted on browser's closing if you don't specify an expiration time.

**Disambiguation**: Cookies with expiration date are *persistent cookies*, otherwise they are *session cookie*.

You could also use [PHP setcookie()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php). Also, have a look at [how cookie works.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Domain_and_Path)

Comment: The session ID [can be transferred in the URL as well](http://es.php.net/manual/en/session.idpassing.php).

Comment: i am not sure how can we do this... can you please help me with an example code.. thank you in advane

Comment: @Àlvaro: Irrelevant, it will only work with a link or a redirection. Not a hard typing as stated in the question's comments.@aparna: editted my answer.

Comment: From what I can tell, it doesn't work with link or redirection either. If you have a way of making that work, I'd be interested.

Answer (score 0):

The most reliable way to be able to transfer sessions so you can 'take control' of them from another browser is using MySQL or some other storage medium for storing sessions, this way a session is held away from a browser and can then be passed around.